# How to create a rails app that makes file accessible via unique auto-generated links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a file that I would like to make available for online download, but only to selected users.

This is the typical scenario I have in mind

> A person who wants the file would typically go to the website and fill
>   out a form to request access to the file.
>
> If I would like to share the file with him/her, I would authorize the
>   user which should generate a unique link that would be sent to the
>   user via email. The link would be valid only for certain time period.

I would be using rails for this. The things that I am looking answers for:

1. What is the right way to generate the unique link for download?
2. How do I start the download of the file when the user clicks on the link within the valid time frame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you'll want to setup a model for storing tokens:

```
rails g model DownloadToken token:string expires_at:timestamp
```

**download_token.rb**

```
class DownloadToken < ActiveRecord::Base  

   attr_accessible :token, :expires_at
   before_create :generate_token

   def generate_token
      self.token = SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=lIO0', 'abc123')
   end

end
```

Next, setup controller to handle the submitted form (or make changes to an existing action) and generate a token, send email, etc.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  def create
    #process submitted form
    ...
    #create a token that expires in 24 hours
    @token = DownloadToken.create(:expires_at => Time.now + 24.hours)
    #send email and redirect..
  end    
end
```

You'll want to make sure that your mailer view includes something like:

```
<%= link_to "Click Me", "/files/downloads?token=#{@token.token}" %>
```

You'll also want to setup a controller responsible for serving the download and it should look something like this:

```
class FileController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_token

  def check_token
    redirect_to :back, :flash => {:error => "Bad link"} if DownloadToken.where("token = ? and expires_at > ?", params[:token], Time.now).nil?
  end

  def download
    send_file '/home/your_app/downloads/yourfile.zip', :type=>"application/zip", :x_sendfile=>true        
  end

end
```

**routes.rb** (assuming Foo is already setup as a RESTful resource)

```
match 'files/download' => 'files#download'
```

This code is untested, but it should cover most of what you need and give you an idea of what direction you'll want to take.

Additional reading:

- [SecureRandom](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom)
- [x_sendfile](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/)
- [ActionMailer basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: In check_token function, it is better to use .present? instead of .nil?. The check_token is true even if the wrong token is given. This is because .nil? does not check for the presence of the record, only .present? can.

Comment: Instead of creating the token with base64 and replacing some characters with 'tr', you can simply generate a token with SecureRandom.hex(13) method.